# about formatDate in google appScript

Tags: google-apps-script

here is my script

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
var date_1  =  parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_1_post), timeZone , "Y"));
```

The value of date_1_post is submitted from form, but when I enter the last 2 dates of year (31/12/2018 & 30/12/2018 ), date_1 will return 2019 not 2018.
this problem only appear by form submit,when i try to get date_1 in spreadsheet in value (31/12/2018 & 30/12/2018 ),that will return 2018.
I can't figure out what's wrong of the script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what the value of date_1_post is in this example:
`var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
var date_1=parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_1_post), timeZone , "Y"));`

If it's something like:
`var date_1=parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2018,12,31), timeZone , "Y"));`

Then the result is 2019 because the month is zero based not one based.  Or just try it in your console.

Check out the [MDN Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)